# How to sum the 30%'s highest number in a column in groups

Tags: r, plyr

First post.

As said in the headline. I can do it with the subset function, but i would like to use `ddply`, which i cant get to work.

For example i would like to sum the 33.33% highest numbers of change for all males that take placebo: -1.7, -1.5, -1.1 = 4.3, and so on for all the different combinations.

To make it a bit more complicated: when it does not add nicely up with the 33.33% (for example when there are 10 datapoints), I would like to get half the average (or .25 if there are only 9 datapoints) of the two numbers in between.

My real dataset is much bigger, so ddply would save me a lot of time. Any suggestions?

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
 subject sex condition before after change
       1   F   placebo   10.1   6.9   -3.2
       2   F   placebo    6.3   4.2   -2.1
       3   M   aspirin   12.4   6.3   -6.1
       4   F   placebo    8.1   6.1   -2.0
       5   M   aspirin   15.2   9.9   -5.3
       6   F   aspirin   10.9   7.0   -3.9
       7   F   aspirin   11.6   8.5   -3.1
       8   M   aspirin    9.5   3.0   -6.5
       9   F   placebo   11.5   9.0   -2.5
      10   M   placebo   11.9  11.0   -0.9
      11   F   aspirin   11.4   8.0   -3.4
      12   M   aspirin   10.0   4.4   -5.6
      13   M   aspirin   12.5   5.4   -7.1
      14   M   placebo   10.6  10.6    0.0
      15   M   aspirin    9.1   4.3   -4.8
      16   F   placebo   12.1  10.2   -1.9
      17   F   placebo   11.0   8.8   -2.2
      18   F   placebo   11.9  10.2   -1.7
      19   M   aspirin    9.1   3.6   -5.5
      20   M   placebo   13.5  12.4   -1.1
      21   M   aspirin   12.0   7.5   -4.5
      22   F   placebo    9.1   7.6   -1.5
      23   M   placebo    9.9   8.0   -1.9
      24   F   placebo    7.6   5.2   -2.4
      25   F   placebo   11.8   9.7   -2.1
      26   F   placebo   11.8  10.7   -1.1
      27   F   aspirin   10.1   7.9   -2.2
      28   M   aspirin   11.6   8.3   -3.3
      29   F   aspirin   11.3   6.8   -4.5
      30   F   placebo   10.3   8.3   -2.0
 ')
```

Comment: Is the **change** guaranteed to be negative? Or are we required to find the sum of absolute values of **change**?

Comment: Also, can you please explain what do you mean by this thing: _ I would like to get half the average (or .25 if there are only 9 datapoints) of the two numbers in between._ with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you would gain by using ddply, here is a suggestion using base R:

```
mean33 <- function(x) mean(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)[seq(1, length.out=length(x)/3)])
tapply(df$change, df$condition, mean33)
# aspirin placebo 
#   -3.18   -1.05
```

To make it quicker you might try `sort.int` instead of `sort` - and definitely the same function would work with ddply.

I didn't quite get the idea of ...

> To make it a bit more complicated: when it does not add nicely up with
>   the 33.33% (for example when there are 10 datapoints), I would like to
>   get half the average (or .25 if there are only 9 datapoints) of the
>   two numbers in between.

(9 can be nicely divided by 3 ..)

... so I didn't try to implement it. Currently, top 1/3 are used but slightly less if N is not equally divisible by 3 (length.out takes the integer part of length(x)/3).

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` (I believe a better package), you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(sex, condition) %>% arrange(desc(change)) %>% summarise(sumChange = sum(change[1:floor(n()/ifelse(n() > 10, 3, 4))]))
```

Look at the conditional fractional computation. You can change that to be whatever you want. Additionally, you can nest multiple `ifelse` statements.

Note: you said sum up...so I used `sum`. You can just as easily substitute other functions like `mean` for example. Also note that you said highest numbers. So, I did a descending order. You can reverse it if you meant highest difference from zero.